# SAP Business One DI API StockTransfer Object Error -1116

Tags: api, sap-business-one-di-api

i'm trying to insert Inventory Transfer using SBO DI API (v9), but every time its executed always failed and return error code

> -1116 Internal error (-5002) occurred

If we change

> oDoc = company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oStockTransfer);

into

> oDoc = company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oStockTransfer**Draft**);

the document was saved but as an Inventory Transfer **DRAFT**, so we need to open SAP GUI to open the draft then add it manually to post as Inventory Transfer Document, this is not what I want to do. I think there are some mandatory fields that I'm missing or DI API not supported to post Inventory Transfer document?, the problem is I don't know how to trace them, the error message is not helpful at all.
FYI, I have created some API like PickList, Inventory Transfer Request but there is no problem at all.

here's my code for your reference:

```
        SAPConnection connection = new SAPConnection();
        SAPbobsCOM.Company company = connection.OpenConnection();

        if (company != null) {
            SAPbobsCOM.IStockTransfer oDoc;
            oDoc = company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oStockTransfer);
            
            //HEADER DEFINITION
            oDoc.Series = 347;  //SERIES NUMBER
            oDoc.FromWarehouse = d["h"]["FROM"].ToString();
            oDoc.ToWarehouse = d["h"]["TO"].ToString();
            oDoc.Comments = "Generated Automatically From WMS [" + d["h"]["NUMBER"].ToString() + "]";
            oDoc.JournalMemo = "Inventory Transfer - WMS";
            oDoc.DocDate = DateTime.Today;
            oDoc.DueDate = DateTime.Today;
            oDoc.DocObjectCode = SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oStockTransfer;

            //DETAIL DEFINITION
            Int16 lines = (short)d["d"].Count();
            
            for(int i = 0; i<lines; i++) {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    oDoc.Lines.Add();
                }

                oDoc.Lines.BaseType = SAPbobsCOM.InvBaseDocTypeEnum.InventoryTransferRequest;
                oDoc.Lines.BaseEntry = Convert.ToInt32(d["h"]["ID"].ToString());   //ID ITR
                oDoc.Lines.BaseLine = i;
                
                oDoc.Lines.ItemCode = d["d"][i]["item_no"].ToString();
                oDoc.Lines.ItemDescription = d["d"][i]["item_description"].ToString();
                oDoc.Lines.WarehouseCode = d["h"]["TO"].ToString();
                oDoc.Lines.FromWarehouseCode = d["h"]["FROM"].ToString();
                oDoc.Lines.Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(d["d"][i]["qty"].ToString());

                oDoc.Lines.BatchNumbers.BatchNumber = d["d"][i]["batch"].ToString();
                oDoc.Lines.BatchNumbers.Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(d["d"][i]["qty"].ToString());
            }

            int status = oDoc.Add();

            if (status == 0)
            {
                callResponse.Code = "OK";
                callResponse.Description = "Success #" + company.GetNewObjectKey();
            }
            else
            {
                callResponse.Code = "ERROR";
                callResponse.Description = company.GetLastErrorCode().ToString() + " " + company.GetLastErrorDescription().ToString();
            };


            return Ok(callResponse);
        }

        callResponse.Code = "ERROR";
        callResponse.Description = "Failed to connect server ! ";
        return Ok(callResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
oDocumento = null;
oDocumento = Documents)SAPB1.myCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oDrafts);
oDocumento.DocObjectCode = BoObjectTypes.oStockTransfer;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but this code will make the document as "Draft", I want to create inventory transfer document with "Release" status.